# Is Lenovo T410 capable of supporting two external monitors at 1080x1920?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I'm interested in the model with nVidia NVS3100M graphics, and I'd like to connect to two external monitors, one via VGA and another via DisplayPort.

Will it be able to support 1080x1920 (both rotated 90 degrees) on both monitors? Also, if I decide to add a third monitor, will it be able to support three through a dock?

Thanks.